Number of significant digits when computing percentages on prices
I have two numbers total and partial that are always rounded to two decimals as they are prices in currencies that have cents (for example: 1.26 €).
Let p be a number so that p = partial x 100 / total
I'd like p to have at most 10 significant digits, for example 22.1234567891
Given this, how can I find the maximum value of total that guarantees that p x total / 100 = partial stays true ?
Example:

total = 1200.67
partial = 122.82

=> p = 10.229288647171995,
but if I keep only significant digits, p = 10.229
because 10.229 x 1200.67 / 100 = 122.8165343 that gives 122.82 when rounded to two decimals.

So, I think your point is that, for these particular values of total and partial, you can't round p to any fewer decimal points and get the same answer (e.g. if you round your p to 10.23, partial would compute to 122.83).  Is that correct?  And if it is ... I'm still not sure I know what your question is about -- are you trying to recreate a p from a total and a partial?  Are you trying to make sure any possible value of partial can exist?  Something else?

Hi @tabstop, sorry I have a hard time explaining this problem

for these particular values of total and partial, you can't round p to any fewer decimal points and get the same answer (e.g. if you round your p to 10.23, partial would compute to 122.83). Is that correct?

yes that's it ! I'm using this in a web application, where the user has access to total, partial and p, and I want to make sure that he can re-do the computations manually and reach the same results

Okay! So now the question is: which calculation are they trying to check?  If you generated partial from a p, then you should just use the p you used to do the calculation.
If you were handed total and partial and you calculated p from them ... well, I guess now we're into the weeds of how much you trust your users to know what's going on -- they should check by doing the same division, and seeing that what they calculate matches what's printed, rather than multiply the calculated percentage.  Is there a reason you don't just leave p at full precision?

But if you do need to cut down p, you are right that it will have to depend on the size of total -- if you round p to the nearest percent, then your jump between consecutive values will be 12.0067, obviously too high; if you round p to have three decimal places, your jump between consecutive values will be .01200 which is too big in general (for instance you can see that 122.81 is unachievable; 10.229% too high, 10.228% too low), so for arbitrary partial you'd need one more digit generally for a spacing of .0012 and every possible cents-value can be output.
